# How to have data allow decimals

Tags: php, html

I made a program that lets 6 grades be entered into a form, and then calculates the letter grade and the average. The only problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to get the form to accept decimals. I tried changing my filter_input statement to sanitize floats, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Grades</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
 <script>
     window.onload = () => {
         document.getElementById('quiz1').focus();
         document.getElementById('quiz1').select();
     }
 </script>
 <style>
     input[type="text"] {width: 4em !important; text-align: right; margin-left: .5em; }
     ul { list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto text-center">
     <h1>Enter Quiz Grades</h1>
     <form action="." method="post">
         <?php
         // declare an array to store bowling scores
         $quizScores = array();
         // declare a variable to be used for the natural counting of the number of games
         $numberOfScores = 6;
         // declare a variable to be used for array elements - subtract 1 since array elements start at 0
         $gamesArrayElements = $numberOfScores - 1;

         for ($i = 0; $i <= $gamesArrayElements; $i++){
             $quizNumber = $i + 1;
             // load values from POST into array elements
             if (strlen($_POST['quiz' . $quizNumber]) > 0){
                 $quizScores[$i] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quiz' . $quizNumber, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
             }
             echo "<div class='form-group form-inline justify-content-center'>\n";
             echo "<label for='quiz$quizNumber'>Quiz $quizNumber: </label>\n";
             echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='quiz$quizNumber' id='quiz$quizNumber' value='$quizScores[$i]'>%\n";
             echo "</div>\n";
         }
         ?>
         <div class="form-group">
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Find Average of <?php echo $numberOfScores; ?> Highest Quiz Grades">
             <a href="." class="btn btn-secondary">Clear</a>
         </div>
     </form>
     <?php
     if (count($quizScores) === $numberOfScores){
         $total = 0;
         echo "<h2>Scores:</h2>\n";
         echo "<ul>\n";
         // for loop to print array elements and add each score to the total
         for ($i = 0; $i <= $gamesArrayElements; $i++){
             echo "<li>$quizScores[$i] " . getLetterGrade($quizScores[$i]) . "</li>\n";
             $total += $quizScores[$i];
         }
         echo "</ul>\n";
         $average = $total / $numberOfScores;
         echo "<h2>Average Score:</h2>\n";
         echo "<p>" . number_format($average, 1, .2) . " - " . getLetterGrade($average) . "</p>\n";
     } else {
         if(count($quizScores) > 0) {
             echo "<h2 class='text-danger'>All textboxes should contain grades.</h2>\n";
         }
     }
     ?>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I changed `number_format($average, 1, .2)` to `number_format($average, 1)` and then I do get the average rounded to one decimal. I also removed the `getLetterGrade()` function because it is not defined in your code. Finally I change the form action to `""`, instead of `"."`, because it didn't work in my test environment.

Perhaps you need to [switch on error reporting in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)? That way you can see what's wrong with your code.